# ASP.Net Core RoleManager<IdentityRole> Async methods causing site to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-identity

I've been trying to get my head wrapped around ASP.Net Core Identity and while I've had some success I'm running into issues that I cannot piece together.

I've created a role management page in my test application that lists the current site roles and has a textbox for a user to create a new role.  The page loads fine and the 1 role I seeded the application with displays for the user, but my form to create a new role crashes on any Async method I attempt to run.

Here's my Startup.cs configuration.  I'm hoping there no issue with this code since I've seen this all over the internet.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Here's how I've initialized my **roleManager** in the Page model.

```
private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

public RolesModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
        }
```

And here's my OnPost method to add a new role.  I've written and rewritten this to try either **RoleExistsAsync** or **CreateAsync** first, but both cause the debugger to stop processing and go straight to page rendering, where the **Model** is *not set to an instance of an object* and the page errors out.  I'm not sure why the error isn't being caught by the **catch** portion either.

```
public async void OnPost()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // creates new role from form data
                    IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole(HttpContext.Request.Form["NewRole"]);

                    var exists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(HttpContext.Request.Form["NewRole"]);
                    if (!exists)
                    {
                        var results = await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                        if (results.Succeeded)
                        {
                            Message = "Success! Role created.";

                            // binds list of roles
                            BindRoles();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: I've added the below HTML form that is attempting the Post...

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Normalized Name</th>
                <th>Concurrency Stamp</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.roles != null)
            {
                @if (Model.roles.Count > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (var r in Model.roles)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@r.Id</td>
                            <td>@r.Name</td>
                            <td>@r.NormalizedName</td>
                            <td>@r.ConcurrencyStamp</td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <em>No roles</em>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }


        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New Role" aria-label="New Role" id="NewRole" name="NewRole">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" rel="button">Add Role</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a model in your view?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov - I'm not sure I understand the question.  My page class is declared as `public class RolesModel : PageModel`.

Comment: Can you post a brief section of your view with the model declarations and the form HTML that posts to the server?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov - I've added the HTML form portion of my page but I'm not sure what you mean by "view".  I'm using Razor pages, not MVC, so I have a cshtml page and the C# code behind it.  What am I missing?  Sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: See that all your model properties and other data that you're using in the page html are instantiated when you return from the `OnPost` handler. Also by returning `void` from your async method the caller is not awaiting the handler to finish its tasks. Change the return type to `Task`.
You could try to return a `Task<IActionResult>` with `RedirectToPage()` call to see if the page will be rendered without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my `OnPost`method to return `Task<IActionResult>` seems to have solved my problem.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
```

Thanks for the help in the comment section.